# Pr2MotorsAnalyzers

Tags: ros, diagnostics, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have read analyzer http://www.ros.org/wiki/diagnostics/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Diagnostic%20Analyzer  and checked it. It works. I use SICK LMS200 with Pioneer-3DX, how can i collect diagnostic data for the pioneer motor and this laser sensor?
regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9104/pr2motorsanalyzers/) by [safzam](https://answers.ros.org/users/118/safzam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-02-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The diagnostics are published by the drivers.  I do not believe either the Sick driver or the Pioneer driver publish diagnostics in this form at the moment.

This mechanism is covered in [REP 107](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0107.html). Adding diagnostics would be a feature enhancement for both these drivers.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-02-17**:
The sicktoolbox_wrapper (SICK driver) definitely does not publish diagnostics right now.